# How to use the withcolumn method with a filter based on more than condition?

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am new to Pyspark

I have this piece of code:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("VALUE", F.when(col('DIFF') < -900000, None).otherwise(col('VALUE')))
```

Is it possible to add another condition in the when clause, something like:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("VALUE", F.when(col('DIFF') < -900000 | col('DIFF') > 900000, None).otherwise(col('VALUE')))
```

However, this throws an Method does not exist error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: Use parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("VALUE", F.when((col('DIFF') < -900000 ) | (col('DIFF') > 900000), None).otherwise(col('VALUE')))
```